# No Python at 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'

Tags: python

i install pycharm and try to run

```
 pip3 install python-binance
```

it show error

```
No Python at 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
```

how can fix that ,
i have pip in

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

i uninstalled previous python version and pycharm .
and reinstall now anf this error happen
how can fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, delete old pycharm project folder where had venv , and create new project folder from pycharm .

Answer (score 0):

your python is installed in this directory `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`.Add this directory to your PATH environment variable.Refer this link [https://www.pythonpool.com/default-python-path/#:~:text=How%20to%20set%20up%20a%20default%20python%20path,python%20path%20Press%20on%20the%20start%20menu.%20](https://www.pythonpool.com/default-python-path/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20set%20up%20a%20default%20python%20path,python%20path%20Press%20on%20the%20start%20menu.%20)

Alternatively you can set PATH from command line using `setx PATH "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;%PATH%"` from windows cmd. This will set the python path permanently.Restart your CMD after that.Then you can call python and pip directly from command line

Comment: already in env path ,

Comment: already can call pip and python in cmd . in pycharm editor only , this problem happen,this may be due to previous env ,where can i find previous env folder

Comment: Did you configured python interpreter path correctly in Pycharm?looks like python is installed in this directory  `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310` and Pycharm is looking in `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0` directory

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted all of the python stuff from the venv/Scripts and then when i ran it, it reinstalled and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error as I installed `venv` using Windows Store Python and got the similar error `No Python at '"C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'`

I opened up `pyevn.cfg` in the `venv` folder and changed all the addresses to the WindowApps above link with the updated link after installing python from python.org. To get the link, just start python and `import sys` and run `sys.prefix` which will provide the location: `'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'`

After updating, I could fire up the correct python executable within the `venv`. I was about to delete the `venv` folder and reinstall which would of taken heaps of time to pip install all my modules.